# Unable to access values in an Array of Objects, from the React state

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, reactjs

After Storing the array of objects in the this.state, I tried to access the value in the object like `Array[random].someValue` but it shows error `Array[random] is undefined`. But it works for `Array[random]` returns an object. Why can't i access the value inside that object...?

```
class Quiz extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: undefined,
            q_no: 0,
            rand_q: {},
            opts: []
        }
        this.newQuestion = this.newQuestion.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        if(this.state.data === undefined) {
            fetch("http://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all")
            .then(data => data.json())
            .then(data => this.setState({data: [data.map((val) => ({name: val.name, flag: val.flag}))]}))
            .then(() => console.log(this.state.data));
        }
    }

    newQuestion() {
        const state = this.state;
        const rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 200);
        this.setState({rand_q: {name: state.data[rand].name, flag: state.data[rand].flag}, opts: [state[rand-1].name, state[rand+1].name, state[rand+2].name]});
    }
```

```
TypeError: state.data[rand] is undefined
newQuestion
src/Quiz.js:30

  27 | newQuestion() {
  28 |     const state = this.state;
  29 |     const rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 200);
> 30 |     this.setState({rand_q: {name: state.data[rand].name, flag: state.data[rand].flag}, opts: [state[rand-1].name, state[rand+1].name, state[rand+2].name]});
     | ^  31 | }
  32 | 
  33 | render() {
```

Please help...

Comment: Is it possible that your JSX has something like `<button onClick={this.newQuestion()} ...`? Because that will run the function during the render, not at the time the button is clicked, which is too early. You need `onClick={() => this.newQuestion()}` instead, and if you use that, you can also remove the `bind` line from the constructor. In general, you might want to display a loading text while `this.state.data` is undefined, using conditional rendering.

Comment: nope.. `<Form newQuestion={this.newQuestion} />`..

Comment: Ok... so where do you call the function then?

Comment: can you post the full code?

Comment: so if you add an extra line before setting the state at line 30, `console.log(this.state.data[rand])` does it give you a value and not undefined?

Comment: `console.log(this.state.data[rand])` this works fine. but the code crashes when `console.log(this.state.data[rand].name)`..

Comment: this doesnt make sense. i see also that you have rand-1,rand+1.rand+2. does these console.log objects or do they console.log undefined?

Comment: if i try to `console.log(this.state.data[rand].name)` it shows 'this.state.data is undefined'. but it works fine with `console.log(this.state.data[rand])` and returns the whole object

Comment: can you post the full code or a codesandbox?

Comment: [link](https://github.com/VivekKashyapS98/GuessFlag) _here is the link to the code.._

Comment: You are calling `this.newQuestion()` at the end of `componentDidMount` (not in your question code though...!), however setting state is async, and `this.state.data` is still empty at the point. You also can't `.then()` setting state, because it doesn't return a Promise. You can however pass a function to `setState()` as 2nd param, and that will run once the state update has finished. Here's my fix: https://codesandbox.io/s/morning-brook-c4txp?file=/src/Quiz.js

Comment: (I also fixed the form: the answers are only shuffled once, and there's a loop for them now)

Comment: Thanks for the help Chris

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor is called before `componentDidMount` so there is no `state.data` available (since you set it to `undefined`).

You either have to move the `newQuestion` call to the render function or to `componentDidUpdate`